# Feature Extraction for training

Tags: python-2.7, pattern-matching, neural-network, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I am having trouble in using feature extraction for object classification.
I need to classify different types of cars but I do not know which feature extraction technique to use for training purpose.

*In short  How can I conclude that (Lets say) Algorithm A is good for my purpose and what features should I look for?`*

Also tell me if there is any `module` to implement feature extraction in python.

Answer (score 1):

The techniques you will use in machine learning will vary depending on your descriptors. Are they continuous or discrete ? Does your oracle estimate a continuous value, or find a discrete one ?

- For example, if your output is continuous, you can use linear regression, SVM...
- For discrete output, you can rely on decision trees, k-means or any clustering technique, multiple discriminant analysis.
- Neural networks can be used for both.

Dealing with discrete descriptors can be a little trickier, you can either :

- transform them in continuous variables
- use regression trees, clustering trees, etc

If you have a lot of descriptors, you might need to select your descriptors during a pre processing step (feature selection) ; you can do it with forward selection for example.

You will really find a lot of stuff in R, so I would suggest you to call R from your Python code. More in this link (http://scienceoss.com/rpy-statistics-in-r-from-python/).

Cheers

Comment: I have heard about gabour filter for feature extraction..can they be good for my purpose? btw I am going to read about them thanks

Comment: Gabour filters can be used for temporal signal processing and image processing. I you are planning to go for image processing, I would suggest you to go SIFTs.